How to enter several words on a separate line from the keyboard in Dart
There is a command in Dart that allows you to enter data into the console:
final input = stdin.readLineSync();

But how could I make it possible to enter one element in a separate line? Something like this:
hello
world
!


Do you want to retrieve all those "lines" as a single line or you want to retrieve an array of (3 lines) lines ?

@Alex I need an array with this three lines/words

Ok, now how would you let the program know that you finished entering ? As this usually this is done by the presence of carriage return and you want to keep trigger (visually) carriage returns then another key/shortcut will be needed to signal that you finished typing (the input).

@Alex I guess I need to pass a number first - the number of words, this way the program can determine when to complete the input

The code bellow contains a small function, readFromInput, that will receive a parameter that tells how many lines you want to get. Also you can retain or not the new lines.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

String readFromInput(int no, {retainNewlines = false}) {
  String result = '';
  while (no-- > 0) {
    String? line =
        stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8, retainNewlines: retainNewlines);
    result = result + (line ?? '');
  }
  return result;
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  String res = readFromInput(3, retainNewlines: true);
  print("Result is: ${res}");
}


I also solved my problem like this:
void main() {
    stdout.write('Enter the number of words: ');
    int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    List<String> words = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String word = stdin.readLineSync()!;
        words.add(word);
    }

    print('The entered words:');
    for (String word in words) {
        print(word);
    }
}

